# How to avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern for this concurrent timer that should reset when the promise completes?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, settimeout

I have written a pretty simply script:

```
{
   waiting: false,

   async handleWaiting(promise, timeout) {
       return new Promise((res, rej) => {
           let loadingStarted = false;

           const timeoutInstance = setTimeout(() => {
               loadingStarted = true;
               this.waiting = true;
           }, timeout);

           const onFinished = () => {
               if (loadingStarted) {
                   this.waiting = false;
               }
               clearTimeout(timeoutInstance);
           }

           promise
               .then((result) => {
                   onFinished();
                   res(result);
               })
               .catch((ex) => {
                   onFinished();
                   rej(ex);
               });
       });
    },

    async searchForTerm(term) {
       this.results = await this.handleWaiting(this.$wire.query(term), 500);
       // do something with the results...
    },
 }
```

It tiggers the waiting spinner for a search field.

Someone wrote me, that:

> Your code has the Explicit Promise construction antipattern! You should use chaining and promise composition instead... Also, a function that returns a promise, but doesn't await anything don't have to be async

I tinkered around with this working code. But I got just error over error!

Can someone help me with this, or at least put me on the right track.

I am not that good with javascript but I am interested in writing it better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return an Ajax result using async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506445/how-to-return-an-ajax-result-using-async-await)

Comment: Just don't create the extra promise, comment it out and add "return" to the promise.then.. And yes, async is not required if you don't await.

Comment: @messerbill No, not at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) for details. Generally speaking, you (mostly) do not need `new Promise` when you already have a promise. You can just reuse the existing one (and chain it if necessary).

Your code can be simplied.

- Remove the unnecessary `new Promise`
- Reuse and return the existing promise
- Remove code duplication and use `Promise#finally` instead

```js
{
  waiting: false,

  handleWaiting(promise, timeout) {
    let loadingStarted = false;

    const timeoutInstance = setTimeout(() => {
      loadingStarted = true;
      this.waiting = true;
    }, timeout);

    return promise.finally(() => {
      if (loadingStarted) {
        this.waiting = false;
      }
      clearTimeout(timeoutInstance);
    });
  },

  async searchForTerm(term) {
    this.results = await this.handleWaiting(this.$wire.query(term), 500);
    // do something with the results...
  },
}
```

And you can probably get rid of `loadingStarted` as well. Is there a reason why you have two state variables for that? You never reset `loadingStarted` anyway.

```js
{
  waiting: false,

  handleWaiting(promise, timeout) {
    const timeoutInstance = setTimeout(() => {
      this.waiting = true;
    }, timeout);
    return promise.finally(() => {
      this.waiting = false;
      clearTimeout(timeoutInstance);
    });
  },

  async searchForTerm(term) {
    this.results = await this.handleWaiting(this.$wire.query(term), 500);
    // do something with the results...
  },
}
```

Comment: Alternative to `.finally()`: `try { return await promise; } finally { … }`

Comment: Notice I'm not a big fan of passing promises as arguments to functions either, what might fit better would be passing a callback to return the promise. (Following the [disposer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915677/what-is-the-promise-disposer-pattern) but basically without an explicit resource).

Comment: "*you can probably get rid of loadingStarted as well. Is there a reason why you have two state variables for that?*" - a reason for that might be multiple concurrent calls to `handleWaiting`. It might be supposed not to happen at all, but still needs to be handled properly if it could occur. Admittedly, the second boolean doesn't actually help at all, a counter (semaphore) would be my suggestion.

Comment: Ok, It's hilarious what I have to learn in order to write good javascript. What would it look like. When you write the short code above of str with the disposer pattern?